# Android lists processing

Tags: android

What's wrong with my code? When I try to separate items with other name than last one, my Android also add element to new list (

```
s = songs.get(0);
lastSong = s.song;
temp_songs.add(s);

for(int i=0; i<songs.size();i++) {
    s = songs.get(i);
    songg = s.song;

    if(songg != lastSong) {
        temp_songs.add(s);
        lastSong = songg;
    }
}
```

For example, I have a sorted list:

```
ABC
ABC
ABC
BCD
BCD
CDE
```

After processing new list (temp_songs) should be:

```
ABC
BCD
CDE
```

But instead I get:

```
ABC
ABC
ABC
BCD
BCD
CDE
```

Comment: Are songg and lastSong strings?

Comment: Are you asking the right question? It seems you are trying to create a list of songs from the original list that doesn't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   lastSong = "";

   for(int i=0; i<songs.size();i++) {
       s = songs.get(i);
       songg = s.song;

       if(!songg.equals(lastSong)){
           temp_songs.add(s);
           lastSong = songg;
       }
   }
```

1. simpler start
2. using == or != in java strings is not right, .equals is right
   read more here: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html